# How to model nested lists with many items using Google Drive Realtime API?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I'd like to model ordered nested lists of uniform items (like what you would see in a standard tree widget) using the Google Drive realtime API. These trees could get quite large, ideally working well with many thousands of items.

One approach would be:

```
Item:
    title: CollaborativeString
    attributes: CollaborativeMap
    children: CollaborativeList // recursivly hold other items
```

But I'm unsure if this is feesible when dealing with a large number of items.

An alternative might be to store all items tree order in a single CollaborativeList and add an additional "level" attribute. Then reconstruct the tree structure based on that level on the client. That would change from having to maintain thousands of CollaborativeLists to just a single big one. Probably lots of other alternatives that I don't know about.

Thanks for pointers on the best way to model this in the Google Drive Realtime API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the total size of the document is within the [size limits](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/build-model#limit_realtime_document_and_mutation_sizes), there shouldn't be a significant performance difference between the approaches from a framework perspective.  (One caveat, using ObjectChangedListeners with a highly connected graph may slow things down.  Prefer registering listeners on the specific objects instead.)

Modeling it as a real tree makes sense, since that will be the easiest to work with, and you can use the new move operation to atomically rearrange items in the lists.